# Minecraft Developing Enviroment not starting (IntelliJ, Forge 1.19.4)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

I want to make a minecraft mod for Forg1 1.19.4 using IntelliJ. Normally, I can start the modded minecraft client through IntelliJ. This won't work and won't give me a error message I understand or even recognize.

Can someone help me?

The main error message coming up in the run console is:

```
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Error log: https://logpaste.com/Gbb1Erha

Main Minecraft log: https://logpaste.com/z8mp0czn

If any extra Information is needed, please tell me.

Comment: From a quick search, it appears to be a bug with AMD graphics drivers. See [this thread](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/117925-forge-1192-43147-crashing-on-startup-with-exit-code-1). If the advice there doesn't help, I would suggest making a post on Forge's forums.